# urxvt keyboard-select working only for the first instance per workspace

Tags: linux, terminal, x11

I'm currently using XMonad and urxvt (urxvtd+urxvtc to be precise) with the keyboard-select extension ([urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls)).

What I observe is that the keyboard-select extension is loaded (or activated, not sure) only for the first urxvt instance per workspace in `XMonad`. I've tried it in `i3` and the behaviour there is even weirder - it works randomly for some instances and it stops working even for those that it has been working for when a new urxvt instance is launched.

I'm not really sure whether the extension does not get loaded or just the hotkey does not take effect. And I'm not sure how to find out which is it as well.

I've tried with urxvt (as opposed to urxvtd/urxvtc combo) and it doesn't make a difference.

Here are my urxvt settings (placed in `.Xresources` and loaded via `xrdb ~/.Xresources` from `.xinitrc`):

```
URxvt*.perl-ext-common: default,tabbed,keyboard-select,url-select
URxvt*.keysym.M-Escape: perl:keyboard-select:activate
URxvt*.keysym.M-s: perl:keyboard-select:search
URxvt*.url-select.launcher: firefox
URxvt*.keysym.M-u: perl:url-select:select_next

Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintlight
Xft.rgba: rgb
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono-8
URxvt.letterSpace: -1

Rxvt*.background: #111111
Rxvt*.foreground: #999999
```